# Sort according to parameters Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to **sort** a query according to the value sent in the `sort` parameter. A `sort` value starting with `-` indicates that the sort should be `desc`.

Examples:

- `url/employee?sort=name` should sort by `name` using `asc`
- `url/employee?sort=-name` should sort by `name` using `desc`
- `url/employee?sort=last_name` should sort by `last_name` using `asc`
- `url/employee?sort=-age` should sort by `age` using `desc`

in Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if your parameter value contains a `-` at the beginning of the string; if it does, remove it and sort using `:desc`, if it doesn't just sort using `:asc`.

Assuming you have a model named `Employee` and controller named `EmployeeController` with an `index` action, you can do the following:

```
# employee_controller.rb

def index
  attribute = params["sort"].sub("-", "")
  order = define_order(params["sort"])
  @employees = Employees.all.order(attribute => order)
end

private

def define_order(attribute)
  attribute.start_with?("-") ? :desc : :asc
end
```